# How can I translate a PostgreSQL hstore column into a row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

What SQL query will translate a [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html) column into a regular table where the distinct keys in all of the hstore rows form the columns in the table and the values fill the rows in the corresponding column?

For example, how can I convert hstore column

```
hstore
------------------------------------
"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3"
"a"=>"4", "b"=>"6", "c"=>"5", "d"=>7
"a"=>"8", "b"=>"3", "c"=>"8"
```

into "equivalent" table

```
a   b   c   d
---------------
 1 | 2 | 3 |
 4 | 6 | 5 | 7 
 8 | 3 | 8 |
```

where the distinct hstore keys a, b, c, and d form the columns in the table and their values fill the rows in each column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this dynamically, but you can do this, if you create a type that matches your output.

```
create table foo (data hstore);
create type foo_type as (a text, b text, c text);

insert into foo (data) 
values 
('a => 1, b => 2'),
('a => 1, b=>2, c => 3'),
('a => 1');

select (populate_record(null::foo_type, data)).*
from foo;
```

returns:

```
a | b | c
--+---+--
1 | 2 |  
1 | 2 | 3
1 |   |
```

Note that you can also use a "table type" if you have a table that matches the columns you want.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is answered, but I've run into a similar problem. I needed to convert hstore values so I could directly insert the data into a table.
This is the solution I've gotten:

```
INSERT INTO foo 
SELECT (populate_record(null::foo, 'a => 1, b=>2, c => 3'::hstore)).*;
```

Of course, the hstore columns must be in the table or they'll be ignored.
Hope this helps other people who ended up here like me. :)